# Symfony 3.3.9 deployment to PHP 5.6 wont render default application

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

I am struggling to get a default Symfony application from PhpStorm 2017.2.1 which works locally (Windows), but seemingly will not deploy to a remote server (Linux) and run.

## Windows setup:

Windows 10, PHPstorm 2017.2.1, php5.6, symfony 3.3.9, default symfony app (namely, I installed Symfony and am using their default app -- no personally written code).     This works, when run with "php bin/console server:run" from a command prompt, and "localhost:8000" in a broswer,  generating "Welcome to Symfony 3.3.9"  "Your application is now ready.  You can start working...."
I believe nothing is wrong here.

## Remote Linux Setup:

Shared hosting, bash 4.2.46, I don't have root access, everything supposed to go in the public_html directory.   A simple one line phpinfo.php file containing only 
    `"<?php phpinfo(); ?>"`

 placed in that directory will render when accessing

```
'www.example.com/phpinfo.php'
```

the usual phpinfo() dump, thus I believe the PHP server is operational.   I'm not sure if there is some configuration error with apache that is causing problems on the server for something more complicated like a default symfony application, or whether the issue is my PHPstorm configuration.

## PHPstorm deploy configuration:

```
SFTP to www.example.com (test connection works, files will upload).   
root path: /home/example/public_html
username and password work, auth type=password.    
Web server root URL=sftp://ftp.example.com, 
and it does allow files to be browsed on the server.
```

## PHPstorm mappings:

```
local path=c:\blah (works, since files upload)
deployment path on server=/
web path on server=/web
I have only one mapping.
```

## PHPstorm excluded paths:

empty

## Upload and Prepare:

Cleared Linux public_html directory of everything including . files.  Uploaded the local app to remote Linux server.   Logged on via SSH and chmod everything public_html and under to 777 (yes, horrible security practice, but this is a test, and there is nothing else on the domain at the moment, and this will rid me of any security protection issues for test).

## Test results, in order:

**Test1:** Browsing to www.example.com results in 
**
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
**

**Test 2:**  Browsing to www.example.com/web results in
**Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
**

**Logs**:  Performing

```
ls -alsgR | grep log
```

produces nothing that appears to be a server logfile.

What process do I follow to get the default application to work?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a web server issue.

My web hosting provider would not allow me to see the httpd.conf file for this shared hosting situation, but did run test cases for me, and for whatever the configuration is, determined that 
  1.  All files within public_html/ need to be have permissions 644 (777 not good enough)
  2.  All directories within public_html/ need to have permissions 755 (777 not good enough).

The two bash commands to do this, run after cd to the public_html/ folder are

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Very frustrating problem solved w.r.t. the server.
  Although I haven't fully checked it out, PHPstorm does appear to have,
   under file/settings/Build/Deployment/Options, an ability to override default 
   protections for files and directories, so I believe it likely that any
   problems occurring with PHPstorm can be fixed by configuration of those
   overrides.